# 'adobe-flashplugin conflicts with flashplugin-downloader' error while trying to install adobe-flashplugin

Tags: package-management, flash, update-manager

I'm having some hard time getting straight with my adobe flash plugin.

**$ sudo apt-get remove --purge adobe-flashplugin flashplugin* nspluginwrapper**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'flashplugin-installer' for regex 'flashplugin*'
Note, selecting 'flashplugin-downloader' for regex 'flashplugin*'
Note, selecting 'adobe-flashplugin' for regex 'flashplugin*'
Note, selecting 'flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound' for regex 'flashplugin*'
Note, selecting 'flashplugin' for regex 'flashplugin*'
Note, selecting 'flashplugin-nonfree' for regex 'flashplugin*'
Note, selecting 'adobe-flashplugin' instead of 'flashplugin-nonfree'
Package nspluginwrapper is not installed, so not removed
Package flashplugin-installer is not installed, so not removed
Package adobe-flashplugin is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 adobe-flash-properties-gtk : Depends: adobe-flashplugin (= 11.1.102.55-0oneiric1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall adobe-flashplugin**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  adobe-flashplugin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6 709 kB of archives.
After this operation, 19,0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: regarding .../adobe-flashplugin_11.1.102.55-0oneiric1_amd64.deb containing adobe-flashplugin:
 adobe-flashplugin conflicts with flashplugin-downloader
  flashplugin-downloader:i386 (version 11.1.102.55ubuntu0.11.10.1) is present and installed.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/adobe-flashplugin_11.1.102.55-0oneiric1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing adobe-flashplugin
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/adobe-flashplugin_11.1.102.55-0oneiric1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT: **sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-downloader**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'flashplugin-downloader' can't be removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 adobe-flash-properties-gtk : Depends: adobe-flashplugin (= 11.1.102.55-0oneiric1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

EDIT#2: **# apt-get -f install**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  adobe-flashplugin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  adobe-flashplugin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6 709 kB of archives.
After this operation, 19,0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: regarding .../adobe-flashplugin_11.1.102.55-0oneiric1_amd64.deb containing adobe-flashplugin:
 adobe-flashplugin conflicts with flashplugin-downloader
  flashplugin-downloader:i386 (version 11.1.102.55ubuntu0.11.10.1) is present and installed.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/adobe-flashplugin_11.1.102.55-0oneiric1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing adobe-flashplugin
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/adobe-flashplugin_11.1.102.55-0oneiric1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of sudo apt-get update - https://gist.github.com/1716225

```
...
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sevenmachines/flash/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources 404 Not Found
...
```

I'm using ubuntu 11.10

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have all the repositories enabled (Partners, Universe, Multiverse etc)?

Comment: er... sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-downloader &&
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin

Comment: @SalihEmin My sources.list is here https://gist.github.com/1716186

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If figured it out myself.

I run **$ apt-config dump|grep Archit**
and it gave

```
APT::Architecture "amd64";
APT::Architectures "";
APT::Architectures:: "amd64";
```

And I fixed it with running:

```
$ sudo -s
# echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
# apt-get update
```

And then updating packages.

Answer (score 1):

> adobe-flashplugin conflicts with flashplugin-downloader

Please uninstall flashplugin-downloader:

```
sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-downloader
```

I suggest trying the packages flashplugin-installer respective flashplugin64-installer if you have troubles installing flash. However, your second command should succeed after removing flashplugin-downloader

Comment: Not able to, that's why I'm surprised. I added output of sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-downloader in my original question.

Comment: did you try sudo apt-get -f install as suggested? Do you read the output messages carefully?

Comment: Of course, see the output above.